# Activar submit de archivos con otro boton

Tags: javascript

```
$(".btn-logo-img").click(function(){
        var subir_btn = document.getElementById("logo");
        subir_btn.click();
    });
```

.logo es un input de tipo file, como se ve muy feo he creado el .btn-logo-img  de tipo boton, al pulsar este pretendo que active el otro.

Lo que pretendo es que .logo siempre este oculto, y que .btn-logo-img haga la funcion del oculto es decir que abra el popup para subir archivo.

Nota: El .logo NUNCA se puede mostrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo el problema que tienes con el código que has puesto. Lo único que te faltaría es crear el html que concuerda con ese código:

```js
$(".btn-logo-img").click(function(){
        var subir_btn = document.getElementById("logo");
        subir_btn.click();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="logo" type="file" hidden>
<button class="btn-logo-img">click</button>
```

Comment: Ya he encontrado el fallo, en el formualrioq ue tenia aplicado esto, el html al poner un boton. Se volvia loco e intentaba enviar el formulario. He cambiado el boton creado nuevo por la etiqueta <a> y ahora si que hace la funcion del input de archivos.

Lo de crear el html lo habia dado por obvio que hay que hacerlo por eso no lo puse.

Comment: Mentras el button no sea del tipo submit no te debería intentar mandar el formulario. Me alegro de que lo hayas solucionado.